# Is there a way to get historical 13-f filings reports from 1970s-1990s?

Tags: edgar

I am struggling to find any source from where I can get 13-f filings before 2000s. EDGAR is mostly after 1999. Does any one know a good source? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thomson Reuters has 13f filing data, but I'm not sure the best way to get it from them. (Through the University of Chicago, I have access to Thomson-Reuters 13F data at [WRDS](https://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/), but that is just for academics.) The file I see only goes back to 1980.

Comment: Yes, I just check with a friend, it only goes back to 1980. May be I need to call SEC and see. Thanks!

Comment: Section 13f [didn't exist before 1975](https://www.sec.gov/divisions/investment/13ffaq.htm). I'm guessing you'll find that SEC rule 13f-1 which requires the 13f filing wasn't operational until the 1980s. For example, see page 26705 of Volume 43 of the Federal Register [here](https://cdn.loc.gov/service/ll/fedreg/fr043/fr043121/fr043121.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Thomson Reuters has 13f filing data. I don't know the best way to get it from them. (If you're an academic, you can use Wharton Research Data Services if your school is a subscriber.)
- Section 13f [didn't exist before 1975](https://www.sec.gov/divisions/investment/13ffaq.htm). I'm guessing you'll find that SEC rule 13f-1 which requires the 13f filing wasn't operational until the 1980s.

  - For example, see [page 26705 of volume 43 of the Federal Register from 1978](https://cdn.loc.gov/service/ll/fedreg/fr043/fr043121/fr043121.pdf) which describes rule 13f-1.